# How to print values from dictionary of your choice in a single line ? IN PYTHON

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose this is a dictionary : `{'name': 'Instagram', 'follower_count': 346, 'description': 'Social media platform', 'country': 'United States'}`

and i want my output like :  `Instagram, Social media platform, United States`

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for?

```
import operator

items_getter = operator.itemgetter('name', 'description', 'country')
print(', '.join(items_getter(dictionary)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the key in condition to whatever value you want to eliminate

```
for i in thisdict:
    if i == "follower_count":
        continue
    else:
        print(thisdict[i])
```

Or you may also use .items method to get key,values and then continue

```
for k,v in thisdict.items():
    if k=="follower_count":
        continue
    else:
        print(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way you can get what you want:

```
dct = {
    'name': 'Instagram', 
    'follower_count': 346, 
    'description': 'Social media platform', 
    'country': 'United States'
}

print(f'{dct['name']}, {dct['description']}, {dct['country']}')
```

Output:

```
Instagram, Social media platform, United States
```